# I have to show either $q_\lambda$ is relatively prime to $p$

Tags: abstract-algebra

let $p(x)\in F[x]$ is monic irreducible polynomial. given $\lambda \in F$. I know $q_\lambda (x)=p(x-\lambda)$ is monic irreducible polynomial. I have to show either $q_\lambda$ is relatively prime to $p$ or it coincides with $p$.(F is a field)

Answer (score 1):

Since $F[x]$ is an Euclidean domain, irreducible and prime are equivalent concepts. Then $p$ and $q_\lambda$ are coprime or associated. Since both are monic, if they are associated, they are equal.